# Issue with Struts2 <s:select> tag

Tags: struts2

I am using hashmap and set it in session.in s:select tag.

```
<s:select name="language" id="language" headerKey="-1"   headerValue="All Languages" cssStyle="width:210px" list="#session.languages"  />
```

While accessing map in jsp using  getting following error sometime,

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'language': The requested list key '#session.languages' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

Please advice on the issue.

Comment: i don't think u have `languages list` set in your session scope. can you post your action class code.

Comment: he does have, so that struts tells him "cannot resolve collection", if he does not have, struts2 will tell him nothing, and shows him nothing

Comment: @Jaiwo99 That's incorrect; if there's an *empty* list, only the select and header option will be present. If there's *no* list you'll get an error message saying there's no collection under that session key, which is what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struts2 doesn't recognize your object type, you should do this.

```
<s:select name="language" list="#session.languages" listKey="id" listValue="name" />
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue at all--the error specifically states that there's no collection under #session.languages.